# Testing Java Optional

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I'm looking into Java Optional and testing some usecases beyond the standard ones.

ok, let's take this example:

```
public void increment(Integer value) {
        if (currentValue != null && endValue != null && currentValue < (endValue - value)) {
            currentValue+=value;
        }
    }
```

currentValue and endValue are `Integer`.

Can the example above be converted in Java8 using Optional?

I was thinking something like that:

```
public void increment(Integer value) {     
        currentValue.filter(a-> a < (endValue.get()-value)).map(???);
    }
```

where currentValue and endValue are `Optional<Integer>`

I'm actually stuck with the `.map` Function.

I would appreciate any suggestion, thanks

Comment: It looks questionable to have an object whose property (`currentValue`) can be/become `null`, which then silently does nothing in its operations (`increment`) , staying in this inoperable condition.

Comment: As Sweeper already said in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44405515/5772882), your code is fine without `Optional`/`OptionalInt`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
currentValue = currentValue.filter(it -> endValue.isPresent())
                           .filter(it -> it < endValue.get() - value)
                           .map(it -> Optional.of(it + value))
                           .orElse(currentValue);
```

**OR** move the `value` into left side is more simpler than above.

```
currentValue = currentValue.map(it -> it + value)
                           .filter(it -> endValue.isPresent())
                           .filter(result -> result < endValue.get() )
                           .map(Optional::of)
                           .orElse(currentValue);
```

**OR**

```
currentValue = currentValue.filter(it -> it < endValue.map(end -> end - value)
                                                      .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE))
                           .map(it -> Optional.of(it + value))
                           .orElse(currentValue);
```

**OR** move the `value` into left side is more simpler than above.

```
currentValue=currentValue.map(it -> it + value)
                         .filter(result->result<endValue.orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE))
                         .map(Optional::of)
                         .orElse(currentValue);
```

**OR** using [Optional#flatMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) instead:

```
currentValue = currentValue.flatMap(it ->
    endValue.filter(end -> it < end - value)
            .map(end -> Optional.of(it + value))
            .orElse(currentValue)
);
```

**OR** move the `value` into the left side then can using ternary-operator simplified:

```
currentValue = currentValue.map(it -> it + value).flatMap(result ->
    endValue.filter(end -> result < end)
            .isPresent() ? Optional.of(result) : currentValue
);
```

Comment: @Eugene yes,sir.  but the first approach is readable than the second one.

Comment: These snippets will set `currentValue` to empty instead of leaving it intact if `current + value > end`.

Comment: @Misha thanks for your feedback, how about it now, sir?

Comment: Hi! Great work, upvoted! But I'm afraid the `if ` is unbeatable... It's much more clear than any approach with optional.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, sir. but he want to transform `if` to `Optional`.

Comment: @holi-java yes, OP asked that, you are right, and your answer is excellent, because you are showing several ways to do it with Optional. But this time, imperative is more readable, I think.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, I agree with you. the flow-control is more sufficiently do such a thing.

Comment: Instead of `currentValue =  … .map(Optional::of).orElse(currentValue);`, you can write `… .ifPresent(v -> currentValue=Optional.of(v));`

Answer (score 1):

Note that I think you code is fine without optionals. If you insist that you want to use the optionals, keep reading.

You just want to add `value` in the `map` function, right? Then do this in the `map` call:

```
x -> x + value
```

Since `map` returns an `Optional<Integer>`, you should assign the result back to `currentValue`:

```
currenValue = currentValue.filter(
    a -> a < endValue.get() - value).map(x -> x + value);
```

However, this will crash if `endValue` does not have a value.

I used this little trick here to make this work:

```
currenValue = currentValue.filter(
    a -> a < endValue.orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE + value) - value).map(x -> x + value).orElse(currentValue);
```

The idea is that if `endValue` is empty, it is replaced with `Integer.MIN_VALUE + value`. `Integer.MIN_VALUE + value - value` is equal to `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, which no number can be smaller than. `a < Integer.MIN_VALUE` must fail.